# Single authentication pipeline for webapi, mvc and signalr supporting basic and forms

Tags: asp.net-mvc, asp.net-web-api, forms-authentication, signalr, basic-authentication

My current services are using MVC to render forms, WebApi to move my viewModels back and forth and signalR for push notifications etc.

If the users are browsing the website they will be using forms auth, but we're introducing some mobile apps and I would like to be able to consume webapi and signalr from the mobile apps using basic auth, without having to maintain two separate sets of controllers.

I have two IPrincipals, a SessionPrincipal and a BasicPrincipal (where Session Principal inherits BasicPrincipal and has some additional contextual data).  The idea is that some controllers will require to be on the website (SessionPrincipal), but everything else can be accessed by both web and mobile users (Basic Principal).  Some won't require any authorisation at all, so can't just deny the request.

My current approach does the following steps to achieve this (some code omitted for brevity)

Global.asax Application_AuthenticateRequest

```
var cultureCookie = Request.Cookies["Culture"];
// Set culture ...

var authHeader = Request.Headers["Authorization"];
if (authHeader != null && authHeader.StartsWith("Basic"))
{
    //Check Username / Password. If okay...
     HttpContext.Current.User = new BasicAuthPrincipal(user);
}
else
{
    var authCookie = Request.Cookies[FormsAuthentication.FormsCookieName];
    if (authCookie != null)
    {
        // Try and resolve Session from encrypted forms auth data.  If okay...
        HttpContext.Current.User = new SessionAuthPrincipal(Id, User, Agent);
    }
}
```

Individual Authorize Filters (SessionMVC, SessionApi, BasicApi) that basically boil down to:

```
return HttpContext.Current.User as SessionPrincipal != null;

// Or

return HttpContext.Current.User as BasicPrincipal != null;
```

So if they were successfully set in global.asax then proceed to the controller.

Now, I have a working implementation of this, so why am I asking for help?

I'm not sure of certain fringe scenarios that may upset this.  Am I asking for trouble for implementing it this way?

I read about HttpContext not being thread safe, but Application_AuthenticateRequest should run before everything else and no further changes are made to that data so I think it should be okay.